# 2 joomla sites in the same webserver

Tags: joomla

people i have to create a second site in the same webserver that i already have my first site. i,m not sure on how i can do this, i would not like to have to change all the url that i have already created. i was thinking on installing a second joomla inside the folder where is the first one. the url will be www.myweb1.com/joomla2, that is something that i would not like is there a way by my dns that i can  change that www.myweb1.com/joomla2, to www.joomla2.com

I just want to create a new joomla site in the same webserver that i already have one joomla site. I,m using apache2 with opensuse. the first site already have a vhost to manage https rewrite conditions.

Any recomendation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the proxy functionality of Apache HTTPD.

Such configuration might look like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.joomla2.com

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://www.myweb1.com/joomla2
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.myweb1.com/joomla2
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```